# Out of memory error in c program for shortest path in a grid

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, priority-queue

I want to create a program that computes the path of minimum cost between 2 elements “S” and “E”,while carrying a pizza. We have a grid (2d array) that consists of `.`, `W`, `X`, `S` and `E`. “X” are walls-obstacles. If we move while carrying the load, every move (L,R,U,D) costs 2. However, we can leave the pizza in a wormhole “W” and take it again from another “W” in our grid, reducing the cost of our moves to 1. Leaving the pizza and taking it again costs 1.

I have written a program, but it consumes a lot of memory and the grader doesn’t accept it. I use a priority queue to store every next situation. The array prev is 3d, because we want to store, because `prev[i][j][0]` means we don’t carry the pizza and `prev[i][j][1]`, means we carry it.
Here is a simple input :

```
S..........XX...X.X.X..XX.
.XXXXXXX.X.XX.X.X....X....
.X.....WXX..X.X.X..X...X.X
...XXXWWWWX...X...X..X.X..
XXX...XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
.W..XE....................
```

Can anyone help?

```
#define MAX_ROWS        1000
#define MAX_COLUMNS     1000
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


char path[1000000] ;
char grid[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
char line[MAX_COLUMNS] ;
int row_coordinate ;
int column_coordinate ;
bool loaded ;

typedef struct {
     bool loaded ;
     int row_coordinate ;
     int column_coordinate ;
}situation ;

typedef struct {
     int row_c ;
     int column_c ;
     char move ;
}previous ;

typedef struct coordinates{
    int row ;
    int column ;
}position ;

typedef struct {
    int priority ;
    situation *data ;
} node_t ;
typedef struct {
    node_t *nodes ;
    int len ;
    int size ;
} heap_t ;

void push (heap_t *h , int priority , situation *data) {
    if (h->len + 1 >= h->size) {
        h->size = h->size ? h->size * 2 : 4;
        h->nodes = (node_t *)realloc(h->nodes, h->size * sizeof (node_t));
    }
    int i = h->len + 1;
    int j = i / 2;
    while (i > 1 && h->nodes[j].priority > priority) {
        h->nodes[i] = h->nodes[j];
        i = j;
        j = j / 2;
    }
    h->nodes[i].priority = priority;
    h->nodes[i].data = data ;
    h->len++;
}

situation *pop (heap_t *h) {
    int i, j, k;
    if (!h->len) {
        return NULL;
    }
    situation *data = h->nodes[1].data;
    h->nodes[1] = h->nodes[h->len];
    h->len--;
    i = 1;
    while (1) {
        k = i;
        j = 2 * i;
        if (j <= h->len && h->nodes[j].priority < h->nodes[k].priority) {
            k = j;
        }
        if (j + 1 <= h->len && h->nodes[j + 1].priority < h->nodes[k].priority) {
            k = j + 1;
        }
        if (k == i) {
            break;
        }
        h->nodes[i] = h->nodes[k];
        i = k;
    }
    h->nodes[i] = h->nodes[h->len + 1];
    return data;
}

int isEmpty(heap_t *ptr_heap){
    if (ptr_heap == NULL){
        return FALSE ;
    }
    if (ptr_heap->size == 0){
        return TRUE ;
    } else {
        return FALSE ;
    }
}

previous prev[1000][1000][2] ;

int main()
{
    FILE *FilePtr;
    int columns=0,rows=0,priority,i,j,k,cost,min_cost,length_of_path,l,c;
    position start ;
    FilePtr = fopen("text2.txt" , "r");
    if(FilePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(line,sizeof line,FilePtr)!= NULL)
    {
        for (columns=0; columns<(strlen(line)-1); ++columns){
            grid[rows][columns]=line[columns] ;
            //initialization of start
            if (grid[rows][columns] == 'S'){
                start.row=rows ;
                start.column=columns ;
            }
        }
        grid[rows][columns]='\0' ;
        ++rows ;
    }
    //until here cool !
    //initialization of init(initial situation)
    situation *init = &(situation){ .loaded = true , .row_coordinate = start.row , .column_coordinate = start.column} ;

    heap_t *h = (heap_t *)calloc(1,sizeof (heap_t)) ;
    //push init in queue with priority = 0
    priority = 0 ;
    push(h,priority,init) ;
    //initialize array of situations prev
    //prev is a 3d array !

    for (i=0; i<rows; ++i){
       for (j=0; j<columns; ++j)
          for (k=0; k < 2; ++k)   {
             prev[i][j][k].move = 'O' ;
             prev[i][j][k].row_c = -1 ;
             prev[i][j][k].column_c = -1 ;
       }
    }
    //prev[init] = "none"
    prev[0][0][1].move = 'n' ;
    //initializations
    min_cost = 0 ;
    cost = 0 ;
    i = 0 ;
    j = 0 ;
    k = 1 ;
    c = 0 ;
    l = 0 ;
    length_of_path = 0 ;
    //initialize the current situation
    situation *current = &(situation){ .loaded = true , .row_coordinate = 0 , .column_coordinate = 0 } ;
    while(!isEmpty(h)){
           current = pop(h) ;
           i = current->row_coordinate ;
           j = current->column_coordinate ;
           if(current->loaded == true){k = 1 ;}
           else {k = 0 ;}
           //printf("%d\n",i) ;
           //printf("%d\n",j) ;
           //printf("%d\n",k) ;
           //exit(1) ;
           //until here cool
           if ((grid[i][j] == 'E' )&&(k == 1)) {
               min_cost = cost ;
               printf("%d\n" , min_cost) ;
               while (prev[i][j][k].move != 'n'){//as long as we are not in the initial situation
                    printf("%d\n" , min_cost) ;
                    //exit(1) ;
                    path[length_of_path] = prev[i][j][k].move ;//we store the path in reverse order
                    length_of_path++ ;
                    if (prev[i][j][k].move == 'L'){j-- ; }
                    else if (prev[i][j][k].move == 'R'){j++ ;}
                    else if(prev[i][j][k].move == 'U'){i-- ;}
                    else if(prev[i][j][k].move == 'D'){i++ ;}
                    else continue ;//we are in warmhole no change of coordinates
               }
               //exit(1) ;
               for (l=length_of_path; l>=0; l--){//prints the solution/best path
                  printf("%d\n" , min_cost) ;
                  printf("%c" , path[l]) ;
               }
               //exit(1) ;
           }
           else {
               //m = "L"
               j-- ;
               //we find the next situation
               if (j>=0){
                 situation *next = &(situation){ .loaded = true , .row_coordinate = i , .column_coordinate = j} ;
                 if (k == 0) {next->loaded = false ;}
                 if (prev[i][j][k].row_c == -1){ // if next doesn't exist in prev
                    //prev[next] = (i,j,m) ;
                    prev[i][j][k].row_c = i ;
                    prev[i][j][k].column_c = j ;
                    prev[i][j][k].move = 'L' ;
                    if (k == 0) {c = 1 ;}//lakis doesn't carry the pizza
                    else {c = 2 ;}
                 }
                 cost = cost + c ;
                 priority = cost + c ;
                 push(h,priority,next) ;
               }
               j++ ; // go back to the begging
               //m = "R"
               j++ ;
               //we find the next situation
               if (j<columns){
                 situation *next = &(situation){ .loaded = true , .row_coordinate = 0 , .column_coordinate = 0} ;
                 if (k == 0) {next->loaded = false ;}
                 if (prev[i][j][k].row_c == -1){
                    //prev[next] = (i,j,m) ;
                    prev[i][j][k].row_c = i ;
                    prev[i][j][k].column_c = j ;
                    prev[i][j][k].move = 'R' ;
                    if (k == 0) {c = 1 ;}//lakis doesn't carry the pizza
                    else {c = 2 ;}
                 }
                 cost = cost + c ;
                 priority = cost + c ;
                 push(h,priority,next) ;
               }
               j-- ;
               //m = "U"
               i-- ;
               //we find the next situation
               if (i>=0){
                 situation *next = &(situation){ .loaded = true , .row_coordinate = i , .column_coordinate = j} ;
                 if (k == 0) {next->loaded = false ;}
                 if (prev[i][j][k].row_c == -1){
                    //prev[next] = (i,j,m) ;
                    prev[i][j][k].row_c = i ;
                    prev[i][j][k].column_c = j ;
                    prev[i][j][k].move = 'U' ;
                    if (k == 0) {c = 1 ;}//lakis doesn't carry the pizza
                    else {c = 2 ;}
                 }
                 cost = cost + c ;
                 priority = cost + c ;
                 push(h,priority,next) ;
               }
               i++ ;
               //m = "D"
               i++ ;
               //we find the next situation
               if (i<rows){
                 situation *next = &(situation){ .loaded = true , .row_coordinate = i , .column_coordinate = j} ;
                 if (k == 0) {next->loaded = false ;}
                 if (prev[i][j][k].row_c == -1){
                    //prev[next] = (i,j,m) ;
                    prev[i][j][k].row_c = i ;
                    prev[i][j][k].column_c = j ;
                    prev[i][j][k].move = 'D' ;
                    if (k == 0) {c = 1 ;}//lakis doesn't carry the pizza
                    else {c = 2 ;}
                 }
                 cost = cost + c ;
                 priority = cost ;
                 push(h,priority,next) ;
               }
               i--;
               // if m = "W"
               c = 1 ; //lakis takes or leaves the pizza
               cost = cost + c ;
               priority = cost ;
               situation *next = &(situation){ .loaded = true , .row_coordinate = i , .column_coordinate = j} ;
               if (k == 0) {next->loaded = false ;}
               push(h,priority,next) ;
           }
    }
    fclose(FilePtr) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show your `text2.txt` file.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need a question to answer to, too.

Comment: @Badda the question is probably "How can I use less memory". But we need the `text2.txt` file.

Comment: The traveling salesman has become a quantum pizza delivery guy?

Comment: S..........XX...X.X.X..XX.
.XXXXXXX.X.XX.X.X....X....
.X.....WXX..X.X.X..X...X.X
...XXXWWWWX...X...X..X.X..
XXX...XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
.W..XE....................  , here is an example of an input

Comment: the grid here is 26x6

Comment: Actually, it sounds like the grader is the correct person to ask this question of.

Comment: no the delivery man can’t traverse through the wormhole , just the pizza . Sorry , i forgot to mention it .

Comment: @SteliosDr for the `text2.txt` and other clarifications please edit your question, text in comments cannot be formatted, especially you cannot put line breaks.

Comment: Between `path`, `grid` and `previous`, you're allocating roughly 26 MB of memory.  That's a lot for a test program, but not in absolute terms on desktop or server machines (embedded systems can be more restricted in memory).

Comment: we have 260mb of memory approximately . Grader says my program is roughly out of memory . What could it possibly be (sorry for my english , i am greek)

Comment: @SteliosDr please edit your question and put the content of the `text2.txt` there.

Comment: I have more inputs , if that helps